Finding the closed form of a power series solution to a differential equation. Why doesn't this work?
When solving the differential equation $\ y''+ty'+y=0\ $ with the power series method, I get the following solutions:
$$y_1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}t^{2n}$$
$$y_2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nt^{2n+1}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}$$
I want to find a closed form for these power series.
This was not part of the exercise I was doing, but I wanted to see if I could do it. However my method doesn't seem to work and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. First I noticed that
$$y_1'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}t^{2n-1}$$
which I rearranged to get $$y_1'=-t\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}t^{2n}=-ty_1$$
By solving the differential equation $\ y_1'=-ty,\ y_1(0)=1$, the result is $\ y_1 = e^{-t^2/2}$. This satisfies the original equation and it matches the series when I compare the graphs in Desmos. It seems to work perfectly.
The problem is when I try to do the same for $y_2$.
$$\begin{align}
y_2' & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nt^{2n}(2n+1)\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{2k+1} \\
& =-t\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}t^{2(n-1)+1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2k+1} \\
& =-t \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n t^{2n+1} \prod_{k=0}^n \frac 1 {2k+1} \\
& = -ty_2
\end{align}$$
This makes no sense to me since that would imply $\ y_2 = e^{-t^2/2} \ $  and when I compare the graphs in Desmos they don't match at all, and it would also imply that $\ e^{-t^2/2}\ $ has two different power series representations, which I don't think is possible.
I think I might be making a very silly mistake somewhere, in which case I'm sorry and this was a waste of time, but if I'm not and there's a different reason why this doesn't work, I would love to hear it.

I don't get it, are you trying to check whether these two solutions satisfy the ODE or you want to find a closed form for these?

As an alternative to the product form, one can also note that $\prod_{k=0}^n (2k+1)=(1)(3)\cdots (2n+1)$ defines the double factorial $(2n+1)!!$. So the second solution can be compactly written as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}$.

You are missing the $n=0$ term of the series representation of $y_2$ when computing $y_2'$. Including it, you obtain instead the ODE $y_2'=1-ty_2$.

You can immediately integrate once ty $y'+ty=C$, and apply the usual first-order solution formula.

You have to correct $y_2'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ ...\ $ to $y_2'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ ...$
$\ $
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}{t^{2n}}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$$
$$\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{2^{-n-1}\sqrt{\pi}}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)!}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{2n+1}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{-t^2}}t\sqrt{\pi}\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-2t^2}\right)\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$$
$$y(t)=c_1e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}+c_2e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{2}t\right)$$

To bypass the need to "recognize" the second power series (which is pretty obscure) one can use the first solution to apply the reduction of order technique. This straightforwardly yields $y_2(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^t e^{x^2/2} ~dx$, which is indeed a valid second solution.
